# How To Transform a Number from Decimal Format to Custom Format?

Tags: python, pandas, format

I have a dataframe in Python where two columns are filled with numbers in decimal format, eg:

a) 1.02234583
b) 0.98232131

I have to transform the columns values into a specific format that goes like:

a) 0102234583
b) 0098232131

The mandatory length for the field is 10 characters (2 integers and 8 decimals) and the separator " . " has to be removed.

```
def calculator_pu():
    base = dataframe
    base['PU Parte'] = 0
    base['PU ContraParte'] = 0
    base = base.reset_index(drop=True)
    base['PU Parte'] = base['Curva Parte'] / base['Valor Base']
    base['PU ContraParte'] = base['Curva ContraParte'] / base['Valor Base']
    base['PU ContraParte'] = base['PU ContraParte'].round(decimals=8)
    base['PU Parte'] = base['PU Parte'].round(decimals=8)
    return base
```

The values are stored in base['PU Parte'] and base['PU ContraParte'].

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method, multiply by 10^8, convert to int, then string, and zfill:

```
df['col'] = (df['col'].mul(10**8)
             .astype(int).astype(str)
             .str.zfill(10)
            )
```

As function:

```
def calculator_pu(s):
    return s.mul(10**8).astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(10)

base[['PU Parte', 'PU ContraParte']] = base[['PU Parte', 'PU ContraParte']].apply(calculator_pu)
```

Example output:

```
     PU Parte PU ContraParte
0  0102234582     0098232131
```

Comment: Mozway, thanks for the answer and it works. 

One question: Why did you apply astype(Int) to the result of the multiplication to shortly after change it to str? I know that zfill method works with str, but why the Int conversion is necessary before?

Comment: Because direct conversion to string would keep the decimal part of the float. It's less efficient to get rid of it as string than numeric data ;)

Comment: Hmm.. I think i got it. When you *10e8 you get a float like xxxxxxx.00000, to remove the decimals you change from float to int.

Thanks :)